# Where does the "zimbra" user get authentication information from

Tags: zimbra

On a typical Zimbra mailserver installation, when logging into the machine as user "zimbra", the commands `zmprov`, etc. will just automagically know how to authenticate to the admin API.

Now I want to run some of my tools that use the SOAP API by themselves - can I somehow access the admin credentials that seem to be already present?

`zmlocalconfig` does not seem to display dedicated admin credentials or tokens. (Just for ldap, etc.)

I did an `strace` on tools like `zmprov`, `zmsoap`, etc. and they all just seem to access `zmlocalconfig`.

(Not sure if this might be better suited for *serverfault*, but since it is about API usage, I thought here would be better)

Answer (score 0):

to access command line with full zimbra power one need to

```
su - zimbra
source /opt/zimbra/bin/zmshutil
zmsetvars
env #to show your env
```